# Qt with codeblocks - undefined reference to vtable

Tags: c++, qt

I've created project in qt (GUI and skeleton for logic), and then I've created QT project in codeblocks in order to do coding part in this IDE.
Unfortunately I'm getting errors in style:  undefined reference to vtable for Calc_Button, etc.
This code compiles fine with Qt but it doesn't want to compile with codeblocks. The same compiler is used.
I can provide code, but it is really quite a lot of it - even just the stubs.
That's how Calc_Button class looks like:

```
#ifndef CALC_BUTTON_H
#define CALC_BUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>

class Calc_Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
protected:

public:
    explicit Calc_Button(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void clicked(QString);

public slots:
    void click()
    {
        emit clicked(QString(this->text()));
    }

};

#endif // CALC_BUTTON_H
```

and this is cpp:

```
#include "calc_button.h"

Calc_Button::Calc_Button(QWidget *parent) :    QPushButton(parent)
{

}
```

Comment: You must be invoking the compiler wrong. Make sure you go through the correct steps with `qmake`, and that you call `g++`, not `gcc`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I do invoke g++ - checked

Comment: Check my answer,Your really problem is aptly demonstrated and solution is to define all virtual functions even if you don't call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is usually misleading but it the actual reason is (usually) that You did not define one of your virtual functions.

Here is a **[sample demo](http://www.ideone.com/q1OZO)**:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    virtual void doSomething() { }
    virtual void doSomethingMore();
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.doSomething();
    obj.doSomethingMore();
    return 0;
}
```

compilation info:

> /home/4VqWl0/ccMjLi2V.o: In function `main':
>
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to`vtable for MyClass`.
>
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to`MyClass::doSomethingMore()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Good Read:

**[What does it mean that the "virtual table" is an unresolved external?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.10)**

Comment: thank you for your answer, and of course I do believe you, but how is it possible that THE SAME compiler compiles this code while invoked from Qt and doesn't compile it when invoked from cb?

Comment: @smallB: Are you sure it is the same compiler that you are using with both the IDE's? I am not sure why the behavior would be different if indeed it is the same.But I am pretty much sure that the problem is not defining a virtual method.Can you find any virtual methods which you have not defined? Define it and then Your error shall vanish I am pretty confident of that.

Comment: it is definitely the same compiler - I've just checked in toolchains in both IDEs - qt and cb - it is gcc 4.6.1. Qt compiles it, cb does not. I just wonder if it has anything to do with some specific to qt issues?

Comment: afaic Calc_Button inherits from QPushButton and there are no pure virtual fncs.

Comment: @smallB: You need to define even the virtual functions which you do not call.Repeating since you said `pure virtual`, No we are talking about `virtual` methods not `pure virtual`.

Comment: so let me get this straight, I need to define in my class Calc_Button EVERY virtual fnc inherited from QPushButton?

Comment: @smallB: It is usually the first inline virtual function in your class.You need to play around a bit by say compiling the sample I posted above on cb.If You can come up with a minimal code example which reproduces the problem,then you can pin-point it out.

Comment: I tried this (I've implemented virtual QSize sizeHint()) and funny enough now it crashes in Qt. Als I have no problems to somehow send you my project (it's very small in size) and you can try it for yourself. I think it would be great if you could solve this. Then the smooth cooperation between qt and cb would be great!

Comment: @smallB: Afraid I neither user CB nor work with QT creator,So I cannot really help out on that.