# undefined reference to vtable when compiling a Qt hello World

Tags: c++, qt

I was following [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html) where I designed a simple window with a single button and try to trigger it. When I compile it I get an error and I don't really understand where it comes from. When I compile a simple program that works, but now when I try to create my own gui using QDesginer it doesn't work anymore. Usually the `vtable` error means that some virtual function is not implemented, but I don't see wheer this should result from. I have looked at similar questions here like [QT C++ error: undefined reference to `vtable for appprinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035662/qt-c-error-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-appprinter)  or [Qt with codeblocks - undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013419/qt-with-codeblocks-undefined-reference-to-vtable) but this doesn't really help.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>

#include "main_frame.h"

class TestMainFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestMainFrame(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~TestMainFrame();

private slots:
    void onTest();

private:
    Ui::MainFrameGUI *ui;
};

TestMainFrame::TestMainFrame(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainFrameGUI)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

TestMainFrame::~TestMainFrame()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TestMainFrame::onTest()
{
    printf("Test\n");
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TestMainFrame w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`main_frame.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainFrameGUI</class>
 <widget class="QFrame" name="MainFrameGUI">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>295</width>
    <height>77</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Testbutton</string>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShape">
   <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShadow">
   <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="mButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Test</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>mButton</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>MainFrameGUI</receiver>
   <slot>onTest()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>303</x>
     <y>38</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>303</x>
     <y>38</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>onTest()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

`build.log`

```
d:\opt\qt-5.2.1\bin\uic.exe -g cpp -o d:\src\c\QTFrameQML\main_frame.h d:\src\c\QTFrameQML\main_frame.ui
g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -g -ID:\opt\qt-5.2.1\include -c d:\src\c\QTFrameQML\main.cpp -o Debug\obj\main.o
g++.exe -LD:\opt\qt-5.2.1\lib -o Debug\QTFrameQML.exe Debug\obj\main.o   -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lcomctl32 -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lGLESv2d -lQt5Widgetsd -mwindows
Debug\obj\main.o: In function `ZN13TestMainFrameC2EP7QWidget':
d:/src/c/QTFrameQML/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `vtable for TestMainFrame'
d:/src/c/QTFrameQML/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `vtable for TestMainFrame'
Debug\obj\main.o: In function `ZN13TestMainFrameD2Ev':
d:/src/c/QTFrameQML/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `vtable for TestMainFrame'
d:/src/c/QTFrameQML/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `vtable for TestMainFrame'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you run `qmake` on this project? BTW, could you show the project file as well?

Comment: I don't use qmake. I compiled Qt opensource with ming w64 and created a normal C++ project in CodeBlocks. And as I said, when I compile a simple hellow world just showing a button, it works. Only when I try to start using a window like this, I get this error.

Comment: You need to process your main.cpp. I dont know how it is done on windows. On linux, it is done like `moc main.cpp`

Comment: @Devolus, if you do not use qmake, how do you create moc files? Simple hellowworld application may not require mocables and it of course works.

Comment: I didn't know that I have to use the `moc` compiler as well, so I will take a look at this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Did you get `ui_main_frame.h` generated by [uic](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html) from your `mainfram.ui`?

Comment: @Tay2510, not yet. I'm working on it, and post an answer if I can solve it.

Comment: @Tay2510, running `moc` worked, so I resolved this problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is often an dependency issue where the moc-compiler where not invoked due to an already existing object file. try to distclean your environment and start qmake again. hope that helps

Comment: I'm not using qmake, but the information that I missed was that I have to process the `.h` files with `moc` when a Qt macro is used there. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT use Q_OBJECT macros in cpp files except you want to manually run the moc... Just move your class definition to main.h, include this in SOURCES and rerun qmake -> works